# Table of contents and references not aligning to margin

Tags: table-of-contents, geometry, thesis

For my dissertation I have to alter the margins (to allow for binding) which I have successfully done using the `geometry` package. My problem is that my `ToC` and references have not moved.

What I have so far is this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=4cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}
\section{Project Objectives}
\section{Literature Review}
\section{Analysis}

\begin{thebibliography}{12}
\end{thebibliography}

\newpage

\begin{appendices}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image: TOC]

[image: Text body]

As you can see, I have set the margins at 2.5, 2.5 and 4 (I haven't bothered with the right margin to allow some room in the text) but the TOC has ignored it. Is there anything I can do to rectify this?

This is also the same for the references.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your document misses `\usepackage{appendix}`. And the question is unclear. Where should the entries move to?

Comment: Sorry, I have omitted a lot from the document as it added unnecessary clutter. The whole thing needs to be moved to the right to allow room for the document to be bound.

Comment: I compiled your document with TeXLive 2015 on Linux and there's a 4cm margin on the left. Use the `showframe` option of `geometry` and it will show you the layout of the margin settings etc.

Comment: Package `showframe` will also help you in determining what left and right hand pages are, which is very important. Another hint: Use kind-of extreme values. A distance of 1 cm is harder to recognize on a 20cm canvas as a distnce of 8cm. Additionally, package `geometry` has a key called `bindingoffset`.

Comment: I have just tried binding offset but still the same problem. I have added another image to better illustrate my problem. As you can see, the TOC is   further to the left than the body of text.

Comment: Do you mean your subsections in the TOC are set in further from the left than the section headings? That is the defaul style and has nothing to do with the `geometry` package. You would need to redefine how the TOC is typeset or (probably a better idea) use a package like `tocloft`, where you could do somethng like `\setlength{\cftsubsectionindent}{0pt}`. You should ask a separate question for your bibliography stuff, because it relies on a competely different set of commands and packages.

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: The posted code works as expected, the question is unclear. `showframe` has been mentioned to determine odd and even pages better, an answer to the question can only be made by an oracle. I vote to close as unclear.